# Array operation PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following format:

```
array([0] => array([0] => value 1), [1] => array([0] => value 2), [2] => array([0] => value 3))
```

and so on. 
I need to reformat that into

```
array([0] => value1, [1] => value2, [2] => value3)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in php, eventually without using foreach?

Comment: `$array = array_column($array, 0);`

Comment: `array_walk($array, function (&$value) { $value = $value[0]; });`